# Get a list of followers who engaged the most with a specific IG page

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I want to get the information of the users who have the most number of likes and comments on a page. For example, 100 top followers who had the most engagement with a page.

I use Instaloader repository and with the following code, I'm able to get the list of followers of a page. But I have no idea to find the followers who have the most engagement with that page

```
import instaloader
from instaloader import Profile

username="my_username"
password="my_password"

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
L.login(username, password)

target = 'target_page_for_scrape_followers'

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, target)

file = open(target + '_followers.txt', "a+")
print(file)
for followers in profile.get_followers():
   username = followers.username
   file.write(username + "\n")
print(profile)


print(username)
file.close()

print("***************************************************************************************** \n")
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Rather than just ask something you want done, it is better to show what you have done before hand and then ask

Comment: I was able to get a list of all the followers of a page using the following repository in GitHub. But, I have no idea how to find the list of users who have interacted the most with that page.  https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader